# POST JSON to Server from CoreData Information

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm somewhat new to iOS development so I'm trying to figure out posting a JSON string to a webserver and getting back some information.  In the first page I ask for the user to give me their first name and last name.  I then generate an ID for them and pass them to the second page.  When the second page loads I want to send a JSON string to the server to tell it the users first name, last name among other things.  The request would be like follows:

```
{
"user":{
    "first_name":"Joe",
    "last_name":"User",
    "device_descriptor":"iPhone",
    "idfa":"12345678",
    "btmacid":"01:23:45:67:89:ab"
    }
}
```

The create response successful would come back as follows:

```
{
    "id": "8",
    "first_name: "Joe",
    "last_name": "User",
    "device_descriptor": "iPhone",
    "created_at": "2014-10-07T05:25:36.119Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-07T05:25:36.119Z",
    "idfa": "12345678",
    "btmacid": "01:23:45:67:89:ab"
}
```

The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataStack.h"
#import "UserInformation.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface WelcomeViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchResultsController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *welcomeTextLabel;

@end

@implementation WelcomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.fetchResultsController performFetch:nil];

    UserInformation *entry = [[self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

    _welcomeTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Welcome " @"%@!", entry.firstName];

    [self postUserInformation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSFetchRequest *)entryFetchRequest{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReqeust = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserInformation"];

    fetchReqeust.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO]];

    return fetchReqeust;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchResultsController {
    if (_fetchResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryFetchRequest];

    _fetchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    return _fetchResultsController;
}

- (void) postUserInformation {
    [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

    [self.fetchResultsController performFetch:nil];

    UserInformation *entry = [[self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];


    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserInformation class]];
    NSDictionary *userInformation = @{
                                      @"id"                 :   @"userID",
                                      @"first_name"         :   @"firstName",
                                      @"last_name"          :   @"lastName",
                                      @"device_descriptor"  :   @"deviceHardwareID",
                                      @"created_at"         :   @"created_at",
                                      @"updated_at"         :   @"updated_at",
                                      @"idfa"               :   @"deviceAdvertisementID",
                                      @"btmacid"            :   @"btmac_Id"
                                      };
    [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userInformation];

    manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/users" keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userInformation];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[userInformation class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

    [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

//    NSDictionary *params = @{
//                             @"id"                 :   entry.userID,
//                             @"first_name"         :   entry.firstName,
//                             @"last_name"          :   entry.lastName,
//                             @"device_descriptor"  :   entry.deviceHardwareID,
//                             @"created_at"         :   entry.createdAt,
//                             @"updated_at"         :   entry.updatedAt,
//                             @"idfa"               :   entry.deviceAdvertisementID,
//                             @"btmacid"            :   entry.btmacID
//                             };

    [manager postObject:userInformation path:@"http://serverendpoint.com/users" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];

}


/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

@end
```

Any help you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create the request mapping with

```
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userInformation];
```

Because the inputs and outputs are the wrong way around. Instead, use the `inverseMapping` from your response mapping.